# Select distinct categories from database

Tags: c#, linq

I am designing the back end of an app and I want to get distinct categories from the database.I am using the following query:

```
var categories = from source in vm.Sources select source.Source_Category.ToList().Distinct();
```

And my model has four fields namely (Source_Name,Source_Link,Source_Subscribed,Source_Category)

The model contains 4 entries in total,two belong to category "News" and other two belong to "Science".But using the above query I'm getting all four entries,Ideally it should return only two items.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should be getting _n_ different Names without any Categories. The code doesn't really match the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select source.Source_Category` if you want to select category name?

Comment: @RohitVats: Sorry,I pasted the wrong code.In my actual code,it is Source_Category only.

Answer (score 6):

You are lacking of the parenthesis, it should be:

```
var categories = (from source in vm.Sources select source.Source_Category)
                 .Distinct();
```

For more readable, I would prefer using lambda:

```
var categories = vm.Sources.Select(s => s.Source_Category)               
                           .Distinct();
```